# suppress one of the options from help when using optparse in python

Tags: python, optparse

Consider the following:

```
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", "--secret", action = "append", type = "string", dest = "filename", default = [], help = "specify the files")
```

I would like to hide the --secret option from the user when help is invoked. Can I do this in the following way?

```
parser.add_option("-f", "--file", action = "append", type = "string", dest = "filename", default = [], help = "specify the files")
parser.add_option("--secret", action = "append", type = "string", dest = "filename", default = [], help = "specify the files")
```

Am I missing any hidden issue by doing so?If so, can anyone suggest an alternative way to achieve this.

Comment: why would you want to do that?

Comment: you ask if you can do it -- did you try it to see what would happen?

Answer (score 5):

Try the `help=SUPPRESS_HELP` trick (see [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/optparse.html#optparse.Option.help)):

```
from optparse import OptionParser, SUPPRESS_HELP

parser.add_option("-f", "--file", action = "append", type = "string", dest = "filename", default = [], help = "specify the files")
parser.add_option("--secret", action = "append", type = "string", dest = "filename", default = [], help=SUPPRESS_HELP)
```

Comment: Thanks! I really meant to type this only in my question by I mistakenly typed the help message for the --secret option also. I have tried it and did see that secret is hidden , but I wanted to know if it is okay to assign the same variable to dest of both the options.